# Why I cannot import a library that is in my pip list?

Tags: python, import, pip, pypng

I have just installed `pypng` library with `sudo -E pip install pypng`. I see this library in the list when I execute `pip list` (the version that I see there is `0.0.18`).

When I start python (or ipython) session and execute

```
import pypng
```

I get

```
ImportError: No module named pypng
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to docs on [github](https://github.com/drj11/pypng#quick-start) you need to import png.

```
import png
png.from_array([[255, 0, 0, 255],
                [0, 255, 255, 0]], 'L').save("small_smiley.png")
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the module name is just png. Try the following:

```
import png
```

Answer (score 1):

Library name is not always the name of installed package. For the `pypng` it is just `png`, as [noted in the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html).

In case, if the documentation does not provide enough info, you could use [`pip show`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/) in order to list all installed files for specified package:

```
$ python -m pip show -f pypng                                                  
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pypng
Version: 0.0.18
Summary: Pure Python PNG image encoder/decoder
Home-page: https://github.com/drj11/pypng
Author: David Jones
Author-email: drj@pobox.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  __pycache__/png.cpython-35.pyc
  png.py
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/INSTALLER
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/METADATA
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/RECORD
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/WHEEL
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/metadata.json
  pypng-0.0.18.dist-info/top_level.txt
```

As you can see, there is `png.py` file, which is being imported with `import png`.